# Having issues with histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to make a histogram graph and unfortunately failed.
Could you please help me?

Here are the codes

```
A <- c("Eu", "Mr", "Avocado")
height <- c(12,26,56)
Nyungwe <- data.frame(A, height)

ggplot(Nyungwe, aes(x= Nyungwe$A, y= Nyungwe$height)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "yellow", col= "green")
```

[image]

Comment: As proposed by mdag02, both `geom_col` and `geom_bar` end up to the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to display is a barplot (for count/proportions by group), not a histogram (distribution of numerical variables by group).

Thus we use `geom_bar` with argument `stat='identity'`

Also, in `ggplot`, no need to re-use the dataframe name when you already mentioned it once.

```
A <- c("Eu", "Mr", "Avocado")

height <- c(12, 26, 56)
 
Nyungwe <- data.frame(A, height)
 
ggplot(data=Nyungwe, aes(x=A, y=height)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity', color="green", fill="yellow")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not an histogram; it's a bar chart with a variable giving the height: you want `geom_col()`. See the [help page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)

And no need to give the dataframe name in `aes()`.

`ggplot(Nyungwe, aes(x= A, y= height))+ geom_col(fill = "yellow", col= "green")`